# Instagram 'Challenge is requried' using Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, instagram-api

I am trying to automate some of my Intsgram interactions such as posting using the following library

https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp

This works great locally, however when I transfer to using Azure Functions I am getting the following error back when logging in.

The specific login code is from the sample here

https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/blob/master/samples/Examples/Program.cs

The troublesome code is this:

```cs
    var userSession = new UserSessionData
    {
        UserName = "Username",
        Password = "Password"
    };

    var delay = RequestDelay.FromSeconds(2, 2);

    InstaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
        .SetUser(userSession)
        .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.All)) // use logger for requests and debug messages
        .SetRequestDelay(delay)
        .Build();

    delay.Disable();
    var logInResult = await InstaApi.LoginAsync();
    delay.Enable();
    if (!logInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unable to login: {logInResult.Info.Message}");
        return false;
    }
```

I am getting this to run no problem locally, however when run on an Azure Function it gets into the if block with message.

"Unable to login: Challenge is required"

Is there a way to bypass this, or perhaps send a challenge to my email which I could accept to allow this interaction from the Azure function?

Any help would be appreciated, this one has me stumped.

**Update**

As per the suggestion in the comments I have tried doing the following after calling login but this still does not work and gives an error "One or more errors occurred"

```cs
    var challengeData = await InstaApi.GetLoggedInChallengeDataInfoAsync();
    var acceptChallenge = await InstaApi.AcceptChallengeAsync();
```

Comment: Could you supply some of your function code?

Comment: I've added some more code, I don't actually run this from the function, instead I have this in a separate dll which I reference and then call, but the code above is the code where I am failing to authenticate on the function properly

Comment: Could you check for a [`ChallengeRequired` result](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/blob/ab6a361d644a58a379b201338f6b01e866d0140e/src/InstagramApiSharp/API/IInstaApi.cs#L432) and if so, use the ["this is me" feature via `AcceptChallengeAsync`?](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp/blob/ab6a361d644a58a379b201338f6b01e866d0140e/src/InstagramApiSharp/API/IInstaApi.cs#L330)

Comment: Reading the documentation suggests this is for when you are already logged in?  "There are two different type of challenge is exists, 1) You receive challenge while you already logged in: "This is me" or "This is not me" option!" I have tried doing what you said but I still get an error, I have updated the support ticket to reflect this.